# Why does a header set via drupal_set_header() revert to text/html?

Tags: views, 6

I'm using the `views_rss` module in Drupal 6. Whenever I build out a View using this plugin, the following header is sent in a `template_preprocess` function:

```
drupal_set_header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8');
```

This seems to be ignored, as the page is ultimately sent with a `text/html` header. It seems that my header is getting appended, but `text/html` is either sent first or last (whichever is ultimately interpreted by the browser) and thus has no effect.

How can I force a non-text/html header for a page output in Drupal 6?

Comment: Can you using curl -I and give me an output of list headers?

So i think in your site, you have other function output this header again, so the return headers have 2 'Content-Type' headers, that's the header come late will override the header come first.

I guess you will have 2 headers like this:


    Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I think you are too late in the template_preprocess hook. The views display will have set it's header already before your hook gets called.

To test my thought have a look at the return value of the function `drupal_set_header`. It shows you all headers sent before.

If I'm right: Try implementing a hook which is is called earlier (maybe even before execution of the view query). Then your header will have precedence.